# i want to use camera overlay as background on click event

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am making the application in cocos2d.I want to use augmented reality in my application so my I have added the code for camera overlay in app delegate and use it in my scene.but problem is that i want to use it run time.My code for where i am adding the background in scene.

```
 @implementation gameSceneDarkRedBeads

 @synthesize window;
 - (id) init {

self = [super init];
appDel=(iChessAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDel.overlay.hidden=YES;


if (self != nil) {

    CCSprite * bg = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"green_bg.png"];
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [self addChild:bg z:0];
    [self addChild:[gameSceneDarkRedBeadsLayer node] z:1];
}
return self;
```

}

Here above i am hiding the overlay.But i want to change my CCSprite to transparent image on click event and  show the overlay.Here i am adding my layers sprites.

```
 @implementation gameSceneDarkRedBeadsLayer

 -(id)init 

 {

self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;

if( (self=[super init])) {

    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] setEffectsVolume:0.0f];
    [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"KompoloiA.mp3"];

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;
```

..........

Please help me where i can define the method to show and hide CCSprite and display the camera view.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this augmented reality tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3997/introduction-to-augmented-reality-on-the-iphone).

Comment: I have implement the same but want to show camera overlay with replace my background on run time then again flip to background with onclick button.